# zip.AddFiles() handle not existing files on the directory just skip those files and zip others existing

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, webforms, ionic-framework

```
try
  {
  Response.Clear();
  Response.BufferOutput = false;
  string archiveName = String.Format("arch{0}.zip",                                  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
  Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + archiveName);

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {                                        
     zip.AddFiles(ListOfPastPapers,"PastPapers");                    
     zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
     Response.Close();
    }
   }
catch (System.Exception ex1)
 {                 
 }
```

I am zipping images using Ionic.Zip dll. I'm giving string type of list to zip.addfiles() with full server path it throws an exception when any image on the specific path not found.

How can I Handle it ?

What I want if image not exists just skip that image and zip all other existing images.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File.Exists(string)` and even `FileInfo.Exists` would help in your case. Just skip to the next iterate for non-existent cases.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the file, check whether the files exists or not.

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{  

 foreach(var name in ListOfPastPapers)
 {
    if(System.IO.File.Exists(name))
    {
       zip.AddFiles(filePath,"PastPapers");                    
       zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
       Response.Close();
     }
   }
}
```